# Method from another class called from inside a class

Tags: php, class, oop

I dont know if its possible in PHP. I tried this code but I got error.

```
class UserAccount extends classDatabase
{
    $validate = new classValidate;
    function login($user, $pass)
    {
       //access a method from classValidate
       $validate->checkInput($user);
    }
}
```

I want to validate user input by using a method from `classValidate`. How to do that? I can't extend `classValidate` because I already extend `classDatabase`.

Please tell me a way how to do this.

Comment: `$validate` isn't in a function, so it would need to be a property, in which case it should be accessed via `$this->validate->checkInput`

Comment: This code should work if in class "classValidate" a method with the signature chechInput($obj) exists.

Comment: Ah sorry sirs but im new quite new in php oop. Icant get most of your answers unless you gave me a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code has a syntax error:

```
class UserAccount extends classDatabase
{
     $validate = new classValidate; // <-- in php you can't do this
```

First you need to specify an access modifier like `public`, `protected`, `private` or at least `var`. Second, php can't "run" code in the declaration, the `= new ClassValidate` will not work here, only constants or literals like `42` or `"some string"` or results of a static method call ([see docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php))

You can move the instantiation to the constructor like this:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->validate = new ClassValidate;
}
```

Note the explicit `$this->`, in php you will always have to type this out.

Finally you need to use the instance in `login()` properly:

```
function login($user, $pass) {
    $this->validate->checkInput($user);
}
```

Comment: Nice, i learned from your explanation. So you are saying that scragar's solution will have a syntax error? I dont have my computet right now so i cant test it hahaha.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it will. Try [this simplified demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vxBlXO). Here's an example that [can be parsed](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mEEZUI)

Comment: I tried it this morning and I got an error like this. "Undefined Property:classUserAccount::$validate".

Comment: arrrgh. sorry hahha. I thought constructor should have single underscore but when I tried to double it, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserAccount extends classDatabase
{
    $validate = null;

    function __construct(){
        $this->validate = new classValidate;
    }

    function login($user, $pass)
    {
       //access a method from classValidate
       $this->validate->checkInput($user);
    }
}
```

Or with scope for added to make it not throw warnings on PHP5

```
class UserAccount extends classDatabase
{
    private $validate = NULL;

    function __construct(){
        $this->validate = new classValidate();
    }

    public function login($user, $pass)
    {
       //access a method from classValidate
       $this->validate->checkInput($user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah i dont hqve my computer right now so i will test your solution tommorow. But big thanks to you hehehe.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW)

Comment: @complex857 is correct about the new not being usable as an initial value, updating code now.